# WordPress wp_oembed_get function returning false

Tags: php, wordpress, oembed

Function is returning false every time, what could be the causes?

```
<?php

require_once("wp-load.php");
$embed_code = wp_oembed_get('http://vimeo.com/XXXXX');
print($embed_code);

?>
```

This is somewhat new to me. Do I need anything else to test this wp_oembed_get function? I have tried https and youtube videos.

Thank you

Comment: I deleted my answer because it wasn't right. I set up your exact file and I didn't have any issues, `print($embed_code)` spit out an iframe for me. You might want to view source, because it was hidden but it showed up in source.

Comment: Thanks, and I have edited the question. No, nothing is showing up, it returns false regardless of what I try. Could some security setting in the server be causing this?

Comment: It very well could be. Can you access vimeo or youtube from the machine you're developing on?

Comment: You mean where WordPress is running? I made a call to the Vimeo video URL using curl and displayed the response html. It seemed to work fine.

Comment: Also, from my machine, yes, the URL/video works fine.

Comment: Well the first thing to do is to gather more information about the problem. [I have modified your script and added some debug output](https://gist.github.com/vstm/12cb0b79462e254b7d5c). Run that script and tell us which "oembed" filters are executed and what the "http_api_debug" shows.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time @vstm! Here's what I got: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/fcdc25f8d31fc9222ea7

Comment: Oh, crap. At the moment it only shows "Array" where it's supposed to display the error message, so once again the essential information is hidden. I have updated my gist so it displays the error messages (hopefully). I'm sorry - can you run it again?

Comment: Here you go: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/efc99814d2d4e7a4a7ad

Comment: It seems like there is a problem with resolving the hostname "vimeo.com" on that system (the error is "Resolving timed out after 5124 milliseconds"). How much control do you have over the faulty system? Can you try to fix the nameservers?

Comment: Thanks again! We have full control over the server, but I'm not the one responsible for it. I'll see what I can find. I did make a curl call to the video URL though and got the HTML back just fine. Would oembed be doing something different?

Comment: Still not able to make this work! I tried resolving the host name as such echo gethostbyname("vimeo.com"); and it works just fine. I'm not sure if this is a DNS issue with the server... Any other ideas @vstm?

Comment: Ok, if `gethostbyname` works then DNS should work, I agree. Is it a Linux box? Is SELinux enabled? Maybe PHP (especially mod_php) is not allowed to make network connections. Try [setting the SELinux boolean for that](http://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/SelinuxBooleans): `setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect on`. Otherwise check out the audit log (`/var/log/audit`) if there are any other restrictions preventing PHP from connecting. Other than that it could also be a firewall thing.

Comment: Thanks again. Yes it is a CentOS 7 Linux install. SELinux is set to permissive, and we doubled checked this with the command getenforce. We have turned the firewall off and tested it and get the same results. :/

Comment: After a lot of trial and error, the only thing that fixed the problem was changing DNS servers on the server, though we can't explain why. Thank you @castis and @vstm! For those having this rare problem, here is another thread that you can find a little bit more info: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/testing-wp_oembed_get-function?replies=1#post-6550008